# Javascript Table multicolumn search with unicodes

Tags: javascript, search, unicode, replace

I've a table and search input.
Here is my search script;

```
var rows = $('table.insert tbody tr');
$('.search').on('input', function() {
  var oldVal = $(this).val();
  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + oldVal.split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$', reg = RegExp(val, 'i'), text;
  $(rows).css({'display' : 'table-row'}).filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).css({'display' : 'none'});
});
```

But when i try to search with unicodes like "ı ç ö ğ ü ş" there is no result to return. So i script these codes;

```
var rows = $('table.insert tbody tr');
$('.search').on('input', function() {
  var oldVal = $(this).val();
  var chars = new Array('üÜ', 'ıI', 'iİ', 'ğĞ', 'şŞ', 'çÇ');

  for (var key in chars) {
    var value = chars[key];

    if ( oldVal.search(value.substr(0,1)) > -1 ) {
      oldVal = oldVal.replace(value.substr(0,1), '['+value+']');
    } else if ( oldVal.search(value.substr(1,1)) > -1 ) {
      oldVal = oldVal.replace(value.substr(1,1), '['+value+']');
    }
  }
  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + oldVal.split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$', reg = RegExp(val, 'i'), text;
  $(rows).css({'display' : 'table-row'}).filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).css({'display' : 'none'});
});
```

Still don't work. The console.log output is (for searching text "hatalı kod")

```
^(?=.*\bhatal[ıI]\b)(?=.*\bkod).*$
```

Can anyone help me? Im stuck at this time.